# Having 2 addresses in Germany

Tags: germany, rental, housing

I'm renting a room in a WG but for various reasons I will be moving into a room in a different WG next month, without cancelling the first contract.

So for a few months, until I manage to cancel the first contract, I will be paying rent for two rooms in different places of the same city.

I want to register my new address at the Bürgeramt so I can get any important letters there. But I don't know what happens with the other address.

Can I be in 2 places?

Staying in the old WG until the contract ends is not a viable option due to mental health concerns.

Comment: If you want all all your mail to reach the new address, you can use the *Nachsendeservice* ot the Post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important is only where you are **living**

- if you have *moved out* of the old flat, you are no longer living there

  - it does not matter if the contract still continues for a while

When you register for the new flat, you can be deregistered  for the old flat automatically.

---

You can be registered to more that one flat (within Germany)

- **primary** and (possibly multiple) **secondary** residences

If you occasionally work in another city and wish to retain a rented room there

- that would be a **secondary** residence

But there can be only one primary residence.
So you must choose which one is which.